# php + oauth: is it possible to make oauth-request from the domain different from app domain

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I'm having an app(site), e.g. on Facebook, domain is `mydomin.com`. Just wondering if there a way to make an oauth request with appid of that app from domain different from `mydomin.com`?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD:** please do not propose solutions specific to concrete oauth server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing your App in Facebook developers page there's a `App Domains` field where you can add multiple domains:

[image]

All requests coming from the added domains will be allowed to interact with the app using AppId and AppSecret.

Comment: thank you,but the question is a bit different.So you say it's impossible to make a request from not registered domain even if I have appid and secret?

Comment: @Eugeny89 yes, you have to add it there to allow it otherwise you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple domains in the app settings on facebook, as long as you add the different one in there it should work fine.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/